# We have an Ionic 3 app that will not successfully start up on an iOS or Android device unless we use the "-l -c" flags. Any suggestions?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

This problem started when we upgraded from Ionic 2 to Ionic 3.  When we run using "ionic run android -l -c", the app starts up with no problem.  When we simply use "ionic run android" or "ionic emulate ios", the app gets stuck on the splash screen.

We have tried uninstalling/reinstalling ionic, the plugins, and all of the node modules.

Here is the system information:

```
$ ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.9 
OS: OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v7.8.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
```

When we run "chrome://inspect/#devices", here is a screenshot of what we see:

[Android Device inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLxwQ.png)

We do see all four of the files referenced in that device inspection in the /platforms/android/assets/www folder.

Here is our plugin information:

```
$ ionic plugin info
cordova-fabric-plugin 1.1.1 "cordova-fabric-plugin"
cordova-plugin-app-name 1.0.0 "App Namer"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.6 "Console"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.3.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.5 "Device"
cordova-plugin-google-analytics 1.7.11 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"
cordova-plugin-ios-no-export-compliance 0.0.1 "iOS No Export Compliance"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.2 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
nl.kingsquare.cordova.background-audio 1.0.1 "background-audio"
```

Answer (score 0):

We made two changes which have helped resolve this problem.

1. We updated per Ionic's instructions to Ionic 3.1.0.  Now our Ionic info looks like:

   ```
   $ ionic info

   Your system information:

   Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
   Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1  (not sure why this doesn't say 3.1.0)
   Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
   Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
   Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.4
   ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
   ios-sim version: 5.0.9 
   OS: OS X El Capitan
   Node Version: v7.8.0
   Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
   ```
2. The "index.html" file had the following line, which we removed:

   ```
   <base href="/">
   ```